# running scrapy from nodejs

Tags: python, node.js, scrapy

I am trying to run a scrapy script from node js project. When I run it through Python IDE using below command it works fine

> > python scrap.py

When the script is executed from nodejs it completes successfully, but doesn't show any error or generate the output file.

Scrap.py

```
def main():
    try:       
        process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
        process.crawl('crawlim')        
        process.start()
        print ("executed")
        sys.stdout.flush()
    except:
        print ("error")
if __name__ == '__main__':
         main()
```

Node file

```
let {PythonShell}=require('python-shell')
 PythonShell.run(path.join(__dirname, '/py/scrap.py'), options, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('finished');
});
```

Comment: Node was able to call the python script, Error was running the scray script. The error message says Spyder unable to find 'crawlim'. But when I run the python script directly it has no issues. it is happening only when running from node.

Answer (score 0):

Use `require('child_process').exec`

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var path = require('path');

var file_path = path.join(__dirname, 'scrap.py');
exec('python ' + file_path, function (error, stdout, stderr) 
{ 
    if(error){
        console.log(stderr);
    }else {
        console.log(stdout);
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to write the scraper depending on the requirement. It also depends on which libraries one has used to get the data(scrapy to crawl the data or selenium to depict browser interaction and fetch the required data). From my personal experience, we were able to call the scraper script (our scraper script uses selenium and BeautifulSoup libraries). 
Below is how we executed the script using the child process.

```
   const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
   const pythonProcess = spawn('python',["./Scraper_script.py",p]);
```

If you are using scrapy spider to crawl the data then this approach doesn't work.